# Qué ocurre cuando leo bytes de System.in.read e introduzco un valor por encima de 127

Tags: java

tengo este código:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Foo3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char car;
        try {
            while ((car = (char)System.in.read()) != (char) -1) {
                if (car != '\n') {
                    System.out.println(car + " " + (int)car);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Entiendo que lee bytes correspondiente al valor ASCII del carácter leído. Y hasta ahí bien, pero qué pasa si introduce esto:

```
á
Ã 195
¡ 161
```

Por qué sale el

```
Ã 195
¡ 161
```

No entiendo ese valor de dónde sale ese valor.

Gracias de antemano.

Un cordial saludo

Comment: pero un byte sin signo son 256....

Comment: El método [read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) lee valores de `0` a `255`.

Comment: `Ã` es `195` y `¡` es `161`, por ende te esta devolviendo estándar `UNICODE`

Answer (score 0):

El comentario de @Synay es correcto, en mi maquina estoy corriendo Windows 10 y la primer linea me dice que el character set por defecto es UTF-8, donde un caracter puede ocupar hasta 4 bytes.

Por este motivo ya no podés asumir que un caracter es un byte, y una alternativa es juntar todos los bytes que se van leyendo en un array para convertirlos en un String en un paso posterior.

Usando el constructor de String que lleva como argumento un array de bytes, conseguís el caracter que habías digitado.

En el ejemplo, usé el constructor donde especifico el character set a utilizar en la decodificación. En este caso también andaría sin ese argumento dado que UTF-8 es el default.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());

        byte car;
        try {
            byte [] input = new byte[4*1024];
            int i=0;
            while ((car = (byte) System.in.read()) != (byte) -1) {

                if(car != (byte) '\n') {
                    input[i++] = car;
                } else {
                    String s = new String(Arrays.copyOf(input, i-1), "UTF-8");
                    System.out.println(s + " " + (int) s.charAt(0));
                    i=0;
                    input = new byte[4*1024];
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Ok, gracias. Y una curiosidad, que IDE usas me parece curioso que te diga el charset. Un saludo

Comment: @pelaitas No olvides de aceptar la respuesta si te sirvió.

Comment: Esta primera línea te muestra el character ser por defecto: `System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());`